# Separate NSData objects

Tags: ios, json, twitter, nsdata

I am using an NSURLConnection to receive a stream of tweets through Twitter. Each tweet that I receive is an NSData object. After the connection receives data and is appended, the log looks like this for the NSData object:

```
Data that is received: <3c68746d 6c3e0a3c 68656164 3e0a3c6d 65746120 68747470 2d657175 
69763d22 436f6e74 656e742d 54797065 2220636f 6e74656e 743d2274 6578742f 68746d6c 
3b206368 61727365 743d7574 662d3822 2f3e0a3c 7469746c 653e4572 726f7220 34303120 
556e6175 74686f72 697a6564 3c2f7469 746c653e 0a3c2f68 6561643e 0a3c626f 64793e0a 
3c68323e 48545450 20455252 4f523a20 3430313c 2f68323e 0a3c703e 50726f62 6c656d20 
61636365 7373696e 6720272f 312f7374 61747573 65732f66 696c7465 722e6a73 6f6e272e 
20526561 736f6e3a 0a3c7072 653e2020 2020556e 61757468 6f72697a 65643c2f 7072653e 
0a202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 
20202020 20202020 20202020 200a2020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 
20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20200a20 20202020 20202020 
20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 
2020200a 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 20202020 
20202020 0a3c2f62 6f64793e 0a3c2f68 746d6c3e 0a>
```

Now my question is, how do I separate those so each is their own NSData object? I cannot parse it using NSJSONSerialization until I am able to do that. I assume each of those addresses is a tweet that needs parsed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the feed u receive and is currently in NSData.
you need to convert it to NSString to able to NSLog and see what the feed actually is or if you are using NSXMLParser to parse the contents from the feed, you can pass this NSData object to parser directly.

for converting NSData to NSString u may use:

```
NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
//autorelease for non-arc environment

NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
```

Comment: Yep it worked in displaying the response. However, it revealed another problem in authenticating with Twitter. I'm going to get that solved and if your solution works I'll accept. +1 for the helping me reveal what's happening!